# How does C language transform char literal to number and vice versa

Tags: c, character-encoding, character, low-level, character-literals

I've been diving into C/low-level programming/system design recently. As a seasoned Java developer I still remember my attemtps to pass SUN Java Certification and questions if **char** type in Java can be cast to **Integer** and how can that be done. That is what I know and remember - numbers up to 255 can be treated both like numbers or characters depending on casting.

Getting to know C I want to know more but I find it hard to find proper answer (tried googling but I usually get gazilion results how just to convert char to int in the code) how does EXACTLY it work, that C compiler/system calls transform number to character and vice versa.

AFAIK in the memory numbers are being stored. So let's assume in the memory cell we store value 65 (which is letter 'A'). So there is a value stored and suddenly C code wants to get it and store into **char** variable. So far so good. And then we issue **printf** procedure with **%c** formatting for given **char** parameter.

And here is where the magic happens - HOW EXACTLY **printf** knows that character with value 65 is letter 'A' (and should display it as a letter). It is a base sign from raw ASCII range (not some funny emoji-style UTF sign). Does it call external STD/libraries/system calls to consult encoding system? I would love some nitty-gritty, low-level explanation or at least link to trusted source.

Comment: In short terms, you need to think about the difference between a character _value_ and its _representation_. Its value is just a number contained in a byte (from 0 to 255 or from -128 to 127 depending on its signedness). Its representation in the printf function depends on the format specifier: with `%c` you tell it to display the character corresponding to the value it contains according to the current conversion standard (e.g. ASCII). Using %d you would see just the value of the unsigned char you are passing to it.

Answer (score 4):

The C language is largely agnostic about the actual encoding of characters. It has a *source character set* which defines how the compiler treats characters in the source code. So, for instance on an old IBM system the source character set might be EBCDIC where 65 does not represent 'A'.

C also has an *execution character set* which defines the meaning of characters in the running program. This is the one that seems more pertinent to your question. But it doesn't really affect the behavior of I/O functions like `printf`. Instead it affects the results of `ctype.h` functions like `isalpha` and `toupper`. `printf` just treats it as a `char` sized value which it receives as an `int` due to variadic functions using default argument promotions (any type smaller than `int` is promoted to `int`, and `float` is promoted to `double`). `printf` then shuffles off the same value to the `stdout` file and then it's somebody else's problem.

If the source character set and execution character set are different, then the compiler will perform the appropriate conversion so the source token `'A'` will be manipulated in the running program as the corresponding `A` from the execution character set. The choice of actual encoding for the two character sets, ie. whether it's ASCII or EBCDIC or something else is implementation defined.

With a console application it is the console or terminal which receives the character value that has to look it up in a font's glyph table to display the correct image of the character.

Character constants are of type `int`. Except for the fact that it is implementation defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned, a `char` can mostly be treated as a narrow integer. The only conversion needed between the two is narrowing or widening (and possibly sign extension).

Comment: The execution character set specifies the mapping from `'A'` to 65 (assuming you meant the character constant). 5.1.1.2.5: "Each source character set member and escape sequence in character constants and
string literals is converted to the corresponding member of the execution character
set;"

Comment: Thanks. I've edited to incorporate that. Am I missing (or misstating) anything else?

Answer (score 4):

> "HOW EXACTLY `printf` knows that character with value 65 is letter 'A' (and should display it as a letter)."

It usually **doesn't**, and it does not even need to. Even the *compiler* does not ***see*** characters `'`, `A` and `'` in the C language fragment

```
char a = 'A';
printf("%c", c);
```

If the source and execution character sets are both ASCII or ASCII-compatible, as is usually the case nowadays, the compiler will have among the stream of bytes the triplet 39, 65, 39 - or rather `00100111 01000001 00100111`. And its parser has been programmed with a rule that something between two `00100111`s is a character literal, and since `01000001` is not a magic value it is translated as is to the final program.

The C program, at runtime, then handles `01000001` all the time (though from time to time it might be `01000001` *zero-extended* to an `int`, e.g. `00000000 00000000 00000000 01000001` on 32-bit systems; adding leading zeroes does not change its numerical value). On some systems, `printf` - or rather the underlying internal file routines - might *translate* the character value `01000001` to something else. But on most systems, `01000001` will be passed to the operating system as is. Then on the operating system - or possibly in a GUI program receiving the output from the operating system - will want to display that character, and then the display font  is consulted for the *glyph* that corresponds to `01000001`, and usually the *glyph* for letter `01000001` looks something like

### A

And that will be displayed to the user.

At no point does the system really operate with **glyphs** or **characters** but just binary numbers. The system in itself is a [Chinese room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room).

---

The real magic of `printf` is not how it handles *characters*, but how it handles *numbers*, as these are converted to *more characters*. While `%c` passes values as-is, `%d` **will** convert such a simple integer value as `0b101111000110000101001110` to stream of *bytes* `0b00110001 0b00110010 0b00110011 0b00110100 0b00110101 0b00110110 0b00110111 0b00111000` so that the display routine will correctly display it as

### 12345678

Comment: So AFAIU it's actually OS/display manager/application showing the output (in pure C bare-bones linux machine - the terminal) of the incoming bytes from the compiled C program? In the 'execution context' (whatever that is) C program does not differentiate whether it's a character or just a number.

Comment: @Chlebik well, something like that but... you always write **bytes** to stdout, and these bytes, small integers, are called **characters** in C. It is the duty of the receiver, whatever it is, to decode these bytes for display, if necessary, and to convert each byte *or sequence of bytes* to *glyphs* for display.

Answer (score -1):

`char` in C is just an integer CHAR_BIT bits long. Usually it is 8 bits long.

> HOW EXACTLY printf knows that character with value 65 is letter 'A'

The implementation knows what characters encoding it uses and pritnf function code takes the appropriate action do output the letter `'A'`

Comment: That is one of many ways `printf` could be implemented, but it is not typically how it is done. `printf` would typically just send a byte with the value `65` to the output stream, without caring about its meaning. If there is a terminal emulator on the other end of the stream (which is often the case), then it is the job of the terminal emulator to turn the value `65` into pixels resembling the letter `'A'`